# Remover componentes em tempo de execução no Delphi com Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Ao criar um TButton dinamicamente em tempo de execução dentro de um TVertScrollBox. Quando preciso apagar este botão ele não some da tela. Esse problema só ocorre rodando a aplicação em Android (no Windows funciona corretamente).

Para apagar os botões criados em tempo de execução dentro do TVertScrollBox eu executo essa rotina:

```
   for i := vsScroll.ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do
      if vsScroll.Components[i] is TButton then
         TButton(vsScroll.Components[i]).Free;
```

Como faço para remover os componentes criados?

OBS.: Não adianta usar `TButton(vsScroll.Components[i]).Destroy` em lugar de `Free`.

Comment: Desta maneira eu acredito que antes do final do "loop" irá gerar um erro, pois a contagem dos componentes já tem sido diminuída a cada remoção.

Comment: Não ficaria viável apenas deixar o objeto invisível ao invés de eliminá-lo? `TButton(vsScroll.Components[i]).Visible := false;`

Comment: @CarlosAndrade, não dá erro no final do loop (o jeito normal sim, dará erro... pode tentar). Sobre tornar o componente invisível, não não é viável. Eles tem que ser eliminados. Afinal a função `Free` tem esse objetivo e como consequência, ao eliminar o objeto, ele se torna invisível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já resolvi. Para Android a função de liberação do componente da memória e consequente exclusão da tela é a `DisposeOf` e não `Free`, como eu costumava usar nos componentes VCL.

O Help do Delphi diz o seguinte:

DisposeOf forces the execution of the destructor code in an object. 
The new Delphi mobile compilers introduce a new dispose pattern implemented by calling DisposeOf, which executes the destructor code even if there are variables with pending references to the object. After the DisposeOf method is called, the object is placed in a special state, the Disposed state. This means that the destructor is not called again if DisposeOf is called again, or if the reference count reaches zero (the moment in which the memory is released).

A rotina de exclusão dos componentes de minha lista criada em tempo de execução ficou assim:

```
   for i := vsScroll.ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do
      if vsScroll.Components[i] is TButton then
         TButton(vsScroll.Components[i]).DisposeOf;
```